# How to put textview and edittext top of listview in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I tried to  put textview and edittext top of listview in layout, but listview is not appearing. When I remove these textview and edittext then the listview appearing.

here is my layout xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/TestLinearLayout">
         <LinearLayout 
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               >
               <TextView  
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:text="@string/hello"
                     android:id="@+id/text"
               />   
               <EditText  
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:id="@+id/editText"
               />   
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView 
               android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
               android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `addHeaderLayout` to add a header to a ListView. See my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/TestLinearLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. can you tell me please what is the use of <requestFocus /> here?

Comment: This is used to prevent soft keyboard to appear when Application starts.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `RelativeLayout` and you can specify `android:layout_below="@+id/header"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a header view to the `ListView` which is just what you want (I think)
[See Documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 0):

The linearLayout above the list view is occupying entire parent as you have given height as `fill_parent` so,

Replace Height of second linear layout with `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/TestLinearLayout">
     <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:id="@+id/layout"
     >
     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    />   
   <EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    />   
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Height of second linear layout with `wrap_content`

do like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/TestLinearLayout">
         <LinearLayout 
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               >
               <TextView  
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:text="@string/hello"
                     android:id="@+id/text"
               />   
               <EditText  
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:id="@+id/editText"
               />   
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView 
               android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
               android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TestLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```